# Chef Recipe API call with node.chef_environment in URL

Tags: json, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Trying to make API call which requires the `node.chef_environment` in the URL

I can't get the `node.chef_environment` part to work in my chef recipe, any help ?

```
require 'net/http'

require 'json'

response = Net::HTTP.get URI('http://1.1.1.1:81/terra/v2/terraform/get/%{node.chef_environment}') 
octocat = JSON.parse response

octocat.keys
ip = octocat['terraform']['modules'][0]['outputs']['public_ip_address']['value'][0]
log ip
```

Any help or advise would be fantastic

regards

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so a few things, first, the string. Ruby uses `#{}` for string interpolation but it has to be inside double quotes, not single. The `%{}` formatting is also a thing but it's used for some funky stuff with Ruby's version of printf and is not what you want here. So all together we have `"http://1.1.1.1:81/terra/v2/terraform/get/#{node.chef_environment}"` for the string.

Second, Chef includes an HTTP client that you should generally use instead of `Net::HTTP` from inside Chef code. In this case:

```
octocat = Chef::HTTP::SimpleJSON('http://1.1.1.1:81/').get("/terra/v2/terraform/get/#{node.chef_environment}")
```

That will handle stuff like redirects, transient failures, and JSON decoding using the faster JSON library Chef includes (ffi-yajl).

Answer (score -2):

simple as

response = Net::HTTP.get URI("http://1.1.1.1:81/terra/v2/terraform/get/" + node.chef_environment)

Comment: Do not add a string with another string... String interpolation is there for that. I.e: `response = Net::HTTP.get URI("http://1.1.1.1:81/terra/v2/terraform/get/#{node.chef_environment}")` which works only withing double quotes; single quotes prevent any string interpolation.

Comment: hiya, tried that it worked when running pure ruby but not in a chef recipe

Comment: Chef recipes are ruby interpreted, so you must have had single quotes or a typo in your code somewhere...